# Supporting both POST data and JSON formatted requests in slim 2

Tags: php, json, slim

I'm maintaining a backend `API` written in slim 2. the api is mostly used by mobile apps, so I'm looking to switch from sending requests as POST data to sending `JSON` formatted strings. This will simplify the api, as the apps currently sending arrays, and even json strings as post data variables.

While it's simple to release an update to the mobile apps and switch to json formatted `POST` requests, the backend api will have to keep supporting both formats for some time until all users will update their apps.

I'm looking to have a replacement function to `$app->request->post()` that will either get the request param from the post data or from the json data, depending on the content type that was sent by the client.

For example, im using `$app->request->post('user_id', 0);` to get the variable from the post data.

I [got](https://github.com/chatwork/slim-json-request/blob/master/src/JsonRequestMiddleware.php) installed into my api and it does convert the json body into an array. the problem is that now each of my api functions have to check either `$app->json_body` array or the `$app->request->post` function to retrieve the request params.

For example:

```
$app->get('/settings', function () use($app, $freeze)
{
   if ($app->json_body != null) {
      $user_id = $app->json_body['user_id'];
   } else {
      $user_id = $app->request->post('user_id', 0);
   }
}
```

It's pretty straigtward creating a global function that does that, but I'm looking to have that function on the slim `$app` instance.

Comment: just create a new url structure, such as `api/v2/.....`

Comment: I didn't try it, but I think you can write your own middleware to add the JSON body attributes to the request. This middleware should be called after the JSON request middleware you already have. If you check the source code of `Slim\Http\Request::post`, you'll see that you probably need to write your JSON attributes to the `$this->env['slim.request.form_hash']` variable, as an array.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using https://github.com/slimphp/Slim-Middleware and ensuring that the requests with a JSON body contain the proper `Content-Type: application/json` header.